# Driver<->OS/App How does it work? An Example

Tags: windows, linux, ipc, device-driver

Lets say I want to make an app, some hardware and a driver to communicate with it. Lets say the device is attached to either the motherboard or via USB. The device would be a board with 8LEDs. The interface i want is

```
bool lock() //true if success
void unlock()
//each bit is matched up to an LED and set means the led is on. 
//Return value is <0 on error. 0 on success. >0 on noncritical error
int  set(char v)
```

Lets say noncritical error means you send the last command in <200ms so it is ignored because the device doesn't want to turn on/off the LEDs that quickly.

Lets say the app that takes in a string of text and uses the device to blink the morse code of the letter/words. The OS doesn't know how the device works. How does the app communicate to the driver? I don't believe a DLL/SO is used because the driver is in its own process.

How does the app talk to the device driver in windows or linux? I'm not interested in how to write a device driver. Just how an app and the kernal communicates with it.

Comment: Hi @acidzombie24, in Linux you can write a simple device driver to access these LEDs. How to access the LEDs depends on which BUS your device is on (GPIO, USB, PCI). Please have a look at http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Comment: @dien I skimmed many of those chapters. They talk about the linux API used to register the device and how it works. I'm sure i can find how to communicate with hardware but i don't know how apps talk to drivers.

Comment: Hi @acidzombie24, your application can talk to the kernel in many ways: procfs and sysfs (please check this link for example http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#s2); read, write and ioctl to a "device file" (please check the chapter 3 and 6 of LDD 3rd for more detail)

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for Windows and linux, I will answer both of your questions.

### Linux:

In the linux world, nearly everything is a file. Everything gets from A to B using by redirecting the output from one binary source to a sink ( file or device file ) or piping the output from one binary to another binary.
The simplest example is a character device, the simplest example of a character device is a serial driver.

The following command:

```
echo ciao > /dev/ttyS0
```

is a perfect example of how to connect user-space to kernel-space.

NOTE: /dev/ttyS0 is the standard nomenclature for a serial-port, and is equivalent to COM1 in Windows.

I have sent at least 4 bytes into the character device /dev/ttyS0.
Code execution starts in kernel-space, so a function open() ( defined in the driver) is called to initialize the serial port, which until-now was off.

This initialization in linux, not only prepares the serial port, but opens a TTY Line. TTY stands for teletype, and it transparently manages moving the "ciao" string to the hardware device.

Here are the steps:

1. Prepare serial line ( or gpio or whatever)
2. Create data buffer in RAM to put data into
3. Map the memory of the hardware addresses into kernel accessible memory space
4. Copy data from the RAM buffer into the memory-mapped hardware address.
5. The hardware device then will do whatever it's designed to do with that data: i.e. modulate and transmit RS232 data or set a GPIO high or low.

### Windows:

In Windows, devices are not usually represented as files, so this needs to be done programatically. The system calls are practically the same, and generally the user-space to kernel-space interface is usually provided by functions of the type:
open(), read(), write(), and close().

### Both:

These calls are generally used for all types of drivers, including graphics and sound drivers. In my linux example, I described how to echo a string into a character device, but I could have also echoed a hex value representing a specific tone or frequency to my audio device which may be found in /dev/audio0.

In the case of a GPIO, the process would be similar:
open(random file or buffer), write (1) or write(0), copyfromuserspacetohwbuffer().

Also in the case of GPIO, linux provides a simple way to access and manipulate GPIO from userspace. Look up the proc filesystem. It exports paths like /proc/gpio/gpio1/value where you can echo 0 or echo 1 from a shell or from an application program very easily.

I hope this clarified your doubt!

-Vittorio